# Как проверить удерживается ли клавиша на Windows os

Tags: rust

Я попытался сделать это с помощью крейта winit, но там есть только нажатие и отпускание. Если вы удерживаете нажатой одну клавишу, а затем нажимаете вторую, то нажатие первой клавиши сбрасывается. Мне нужно знать, удерживается ли клавиша в данный момент нажатой или нет, независимо от других клавиш. Так как это сделано в библиотеке keyboard на python функция is_pressed()

Я не нашел ничего подобного на crates.io . Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Библиотек для этой цели я не знаю, но что вам мешает завести булеву переменную (или массив) для каждой интересующей клавиши и следить за их состоянием?

Answer (score 0):

Можно при обработке события нажатия клавиши присваивать какой-нибудь переменной, скажем, IsPressed_Shift, значение true, и при обработке события отпускания клавиши значение false. Пока в переменной true, клавиша зажата. Или при нажатии другой клавиши вбрасывается ивент отпуска зажатой?